# Custom Permalink Structure with Custom Post Types Using Custom Taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types

After a pretty exhaustive search, I'm stumped.

I have a Wordpress custom post type named: listings. Listings have taxonomies called Services and Areas.

The default structure is

**/listing/%post-name%**

I'm trying to achieve a structure that looks like:

**/%services%/%areas%/%post-name%**

I was able to achieve something close using the plugin [Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) which gives me this working URL:

**/listings/%services%/%areas%/%post-name%**

And then used the code

```
function gp_remove_cpt_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'listing' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'gp_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 3 );
```

That shows a permalink of what I want when I edit the listing but there's a 404 error when I go to that URL. I'm not sure where to go from here. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be using the `rewrite` and `'with_front` arguments while registering the post type. Try this..

```
'with_front' => false,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '%services%/%areas%'),
```

Then add a filter to `post_type_link` to replace the tags with terms.

```
function wpse277778_rewrite_urls( $url, $post ) {

   if ( 'listings' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        $services = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'services' );
        $areas = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'areas' );

        $url = str_replace( '%services%', $services[0]->slug, $url );
        $url = str_replace( '%areas%', $areas[0]->slug, $url );


    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpse277778_rewrite_urls', 10, 2 );
```

Please note, this is a barebone code and you need to do some checking with conditional tags to output error free `$url`. Also, you should set a default services and area in case no terms are associated.

Comment: After a bit more work, I discovered this solution is causing a 404 error for pages. Most of the discussions I found suggested it was a conflict with a page/post. Since I have a 'services' called hotel and a page called hotels, the /hotel/ was redirecting to /hotels/. I implemented code to prevent predictive redirects. That didn't fix it.

So the CPT permalink works but pages don't. I also tried doing %services%-%areas% instead of a / between the two. The pages and CPTs now work. This solution works good for me. However, now there's no archive page for %services%-%areas% 

Suggestions?